# Titanium Mobile : Requested module not found

Tags: android, mobile, titanium-mobile, titanium-modules

I am trying to solve a little problem since yesterday, but no solution found yet, I have everything installed for Titanium Mobile on my Ubuntu 10.04 LTS, but i still couldn't figure out where exactly i need to add a module. All the documentations talks about installing the module in  */Library/Application Support/Titanium/modules* on MacOS which i don't have in Ubuntu.
I added the module under *~/.titanium/modules* after extracting it from the zip, also added in tiapp.xml

```
<modules>
         <module version="0.3">com.googlecode.quicktigame2d</module>
</modules>
```

but i still get the error

```
 Requested module not found : com.googlecode.quicktigame2d
```

any help is appreciated.

Comment: what is the name of your version folder?

Comment: the version folder name is 0.3,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is in name of module file. This is the problem for all Titanium modules on Ubuntu and other Linux systems because they are case sensitive for file names.

Just change (for example module):

```
~/.titanium/modules/android/com.googlecode.quicktigame2d/0.9/QuickTiGame2dModuleAndroid.jar
```

To

```
~/.titanium/modules/android/com.googlecode.quicktigame2d/0.9/quicktigame2dmoduleandroid.jar
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: thnx, never thought about that, I had to develop my Ti Apps under Windows, now I am getting back to Ubuntu ;) So the thing was just to remove uppercase letter from any module name that is going to  be used.
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 5):

windows - your module should place in

```
C:\Users\<<username>>\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\modules\android
```

and you can download com.googlecode.quicktigame2d module from

[quicktigame2d](http://code.google.com/p/quicktigame2d/downloads/detail?name=com.googlecode.quicktigame2d-android-1.3.zip&can=4&q=)

and unzip on above folder